# jquery interval impulse appointing a new random instead of checking the correct answer

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this jQuery game below made with aspx which is bound to an interval 3000.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;                                    //start timer
    interval = setInterval(function () {             //write timer function
        var num1 = parseInt($("#Label1").html());    //number1 is my label1
        var num2 = parseInt($("#Label3").html());    //number2 is my label3
        var total = num1 + num2;                     //find total of these two
        var entry = parseInt($("#TextBox1").val());  //the number your enter is entry
        if (entry == total)                          //the timer will check every 100 ms if they match
            $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");         //if they match, move the car 25 px to the right
            $('#Button1').trigger('click');          //and trigger button1, so button1 throws new dice and car doesn't move further
    }, 3000);
});
```

I want the interval impulse to check if the numbers match and move the .car div along the x axis. However, I get the impulse appointing a new random variable every 3000ms, instead of checking if the entry and total var are equal and then act the car += 25 px to the right. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean for the button trigger to actually be part of the equality check, so you need brackets:

```
if (entry == total){              //the timer will check every 100 ms if they match
    $(".car").css("left", "+=25px");  //if they match, move the car 25 px to the right
    $('#Button1').trigger('click');   //and trigger button1, so button1 throws new dice and car doesn't move further
}
```

Comment: @codinfreak no problem at all!